# Nginx PHP-FPM alias path

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm really giving up on this. I have nginx+PHP-FPM, just trying to alias a path.
Desired:

https://example.com/api/v1.0/ -> /my/folder/v1.0/

I've tried alias:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    index index.php;

    location /api/v1.0/ {
        index index.php;
        alias /my/folder/v1.0/;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
}
```

Nope. The logs reports that nginx is trying to access:

```
/etc/nginx/html/api/v1.0
```

So i changed the root:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /my/folder/v1.0/;
    index index.php;

    location /api/v1.0/ {
        index index.php;
        alias /my/folder/v1.0/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

}

Nope. Now the alias is ignored and nginx trying to access:

```
/my/folder/v1.0/api/v1.0
```

I'm out of ideas, could you please help me?

Comment: Do you have other things in your server config? That initial config should work as intended…

Comment: Hi George, I'm behind a proxy on docker (jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine-0.7.0), don't know if it does matter...no other server config.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to reproduce and fix it locally.
Here's what I ended up with:

```
        # where the actual API is
        root   /1int/code/test/nginx; 

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            try_files $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # This basically drops /api/1.0 prefix from the URL
        location ^~ /api/1.0 {
                rewrite ^/api/1.0/(.*)$ /$1 last;
        }
```

With this config, when I access `/api/1.0/api.php` it fetches `<root>/api.php`

Comment: Sorry and thanks for your time, but this is not what I'm looking for, it's too specific, I need a more "clean" solution without rewrite...

Comment: Ok, so what are the requirements for the clean solution then?